# How to choose optimized Linux-ck kernel?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, intel-core-i7

I have a question that are all 14nm intel cpu use the same micro architecture?
E.g (sky lake, kaby lake, coffee lake, whisky lake).
PS: Linux-ck repo only have sky lake version
, which is the first generation of 14nm nano architecture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer in [this issue](https://github.com/graysky2/kernel_gcc_patch/issues/29). Basically, if you want to decide which architecture parameter you should use to optimize your program.  You can simply run `gcc -c -Q -march=native --help=target | grep march && rm ./help-dummy.o` on Linux.